# I try to understand [c code -> assembly] code

Tags: c, assembly

I try to understand [c code -> assembly] code

```
void node::Check( data & _data1, vector<data2*>& _data2)
{

-> push ebp
-> mov ebp,esp 
-> push ebx

if (TryToCheck(_data1.a, _data1.b))

-> mov ebx,dword ptr [_data1]
```

1. I'm not sure what this line does
   What is the meaning of this line,

   ```
   push esi
   mov esi,ecx
   ```
2. `ecx` is a value for counting as I know .
   Why save the value of `ecx` in `esi`?

   ```
   mov eax,dword ptr [esi+50h]
   ```
3. What does this mean the value, `50h`?

   ```
   mov eax,dword ptr [eax+4]
   lea edx,[ebx+40h] 
   lea ecx,[esi+50h] 
   push edx 
   lea edx,[ebx+50h] 
   push edx 
   call eax 
   test al,al 
   je node::Check+7Fh
   ```

Comment: On the 8086, `cx` was intended for counting, yes. Nowadays, it may be used to hold addresses and more. You should show us the whole code.

Comment: 50h is 50 in hex notation, meaning 5*16^1 + 0*16^0 = 80

Comment: I added rest assembly code

Comment: @user2523112 add some of the c code

Comment: "What is the meaning of this line" ... do you actually understand assembly at all? What part don't you understand? The *entire* line?

Comment: The source is C++, not C. And that is also important when analyzing the generated assembly because of virtual function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
```

This saves the caller's stackframe pointer (`push ebp`) and sets up your stackframe pointer (`mov ebp,esp`).

```
push ebx
```

This saves `ebx` on the stack. Somewhere later, before the return,  you will see a `pop ebx`.

```
mov ebx,dword ptr [_data1]
```

This moves the content of location `_data1` into the `ebx` register. The debugger shows you a symbolic name; if you would look more closely you will see `move ebx,dword ptr [ebp+12]`. Here the parameters of the caller are accessed using your stackframe pointer in `ebp`.

```
push esi
mov esi,ecx
```

This saves `esi` and then moves the value of `ecx` into `esi`.

```
mov eax,dword ptr [esi+50h]
```

This moves the value of the memory location at `esi+50h` into `eax`.

Sometimes you musn't worry too much about the assembler the compiler generates. It maybe sub-optimal or may be so optimized that you can't recognize your original statements.